# How to POST to form with redirect

Tags: 2013, custom-form, redirect, postback

I have been trying to do this for hours now but no luck.

I have an application page in which there is a form. When user clicks Submit button, form values are submitted to an external site where user enters his credit card number etc. and complete transaction.

I am trying to submit this form with POST to that external site but it is not working.

If I make this form `runat=server` then I get error because SharePoint automatically adds its own form in page so now we have two server side forms.

I tried using Javascript submit methods like `this.form.submit()`, `window.document.myform.submit()`, `document.getElementById("myform").submit()` and `document.getElementById["myform"].submit()` but I get javascript error that this method "submit" is not available.

I have seen countless examples on internet and they all seem to create a form at run time and submit it using client side method for e.g. `this.form.submit()` which doesn't work in my case.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I fixed it by creating a new page in the middle. I pass values to this page and then this page submits the form. Since this new page is not part of master page, hence I can use my own form and submit it to external site.